# What will Oersted's experiment result be with the following conditions?

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose we have a metal wire piece connected to a constant voltage, we want to measure the magnetic field of this wire in three different points and at a given time interval. The test tells us that we start to heat the middle spot of this wire with a Bunsen burner until the wire be red-hot in this area. The question now is, what will be the diagram of the changes in the magnetic field from the beginning of the flame to the moment of red-hoting the wire in three regions? before this point, this point and after this point.

How can the results of the experiment be interpreted?

Answer (score 0):

Heating the wire will increase its resistance and decrease the current (for a constant voltage). So the magnetic field that the wire produces outside itself will be reduced. The current will fall to a minimum while the wire is becoming red hot. For a wire of diameter less than 1 mm or so, this will be a matter of a few seconds.

I'm afraid that I can't see the significance of heating the wire in three different places. In fact I suspect that I've missed the point of the question!